Azure Data Factory get Business Central General Ledger Entries
I have created an OData LinkedService and connected it to Business Central as per screenshot:

Then when I run the pipeline or preview, I am getting the following error:
Operation on target Copy data1 failed: Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=ODataRequestNotSucceeded,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Requesting response from path G_LEntries and query failed with status code NotFound and message {"error":{"code":"Internal_CompanyNotFound","message":"Cannot process the request because the default company cannot be found. You can specify a default company in the service configuration file, or specify one for each tenant, or you can add a query string in the form of "company=[name]". You can see the available companies by accessing the default OData web service, Company. For more information, see "OData Web Services" in Help. ,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.ODataConnector,'

I don't know if this is the way to pass the parameters or whether it can be managed in another way. I have changed the parameter name multiple times, to Company, Companies, company, companies, companyname, defaultcompany but I continue to recieve the same error.


I don't know if this is the way to pass the parameters or whether it can be managed in another way

After creating the linked service parameter, you need to use that in the OData URL with string interpolations @{<linked_service_parameter>}. The linked service name can be anything. It's the value that you pass to that will give the error.
If you want to pass your value samplecompany to the linked service URL through parameter, first you need to include it like below sample.
https://<ODATA_org>/<your_URL>/@{linkedService().<your_linkedservice_parameter_name>}

Here, my linked service parameter name is name. If your parameter name is Company, add it at your required place like @linkedService().Company.

Now, give the required value to that parameter.

Also, in the OData URLs, the special characters should be given as encoded. For example, for the value My Company the encoded value in the URL is My%20Company. So, give the expression @encodeUriComponent('<your_value>') to your parameter which encodes the normal string to OData URL format in case of special characters.
